# Condition to check a variable value present or not

Tags: linux, unix, autosys

there is a autosys job, whicn has 3 jobs init. all 3 jobs call a common script and there 3 diffrent profiles one for each of them.these 3 jobs called from 3 different machines
.Each profile has got a varialble and this varible contains a fixed value specfic to the machine. 
In the comomna scirpt i wnt to execute code based on teh value in the variable passed.
If the variable matches the value in the profile of a machine the code for that machine will be executed.how can I check if the varialbe received in the common script is also present in the profile of the machine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Old fashioned way I fall back on (in sh) is :

```
if [ -z "$VarToCheck" ] ; then
    echo "Variable not set"
fi
```

There is probably a more correct way though. Do you care if a variable exists but has 0 length?